# libphp5.so missing

Tags: php, linux

i installed php-5.2.17 with the following commands

```
./configure
make
make install
```

installation went fine. but i dont find libphp5.so file can any one suggest me what went wrong and how to fix this error.

Comment: what distro of linux are you using?

Comment: one who has down voted. answer to my question. you cant just down vote.

Comment: any update? I got this problem to after make install

Comment: I have the same problem with PHP 5.6.36 (stable version). I also can't find that file.

Answer (score 23):

Try libapache2-mod-php5 package,  it'll probably resolve it.

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5
```

(assuming you're already after: sudo apt-get install php5)

Comment: Can't use apt-get with PHP installation: http://php.net/manual/en/install.unix.apache2.php.

Answer (score 14):

First find out the location of apxs (apache auto configuration system):

```
$ which apxs
/usr/bin/apxs
```

Find which version of apache you have installed:

```
$ apachectl -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.7 (Unix)
Server built:   Nov 30 2013 00:31:59
```

Then you configure the PHP install with the location to your apxs, and your version of apache.

For Apache 2.X, run

```
$ ./configure --with-apxs2=/usr/bin/apxs
```

For Apache 1.X, run

```
$ ./configure --with-apxs=/usr/bin/apxs
```

Followed by

```
$ make
$ make install
```

When it's building, you should see the line:

```
...
libtool: install: install .libs/libphp5.so /usr/lib/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
...
```

[Original solution here](https://superuser.com/questions/289320/php-build-tutorial-assumes-libphp5-so-was-built-it-wasnt)

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem. I had installed php56.x86_64 from remi-safe, but when I installed php.x86_64 from remi-php56, then the library downloaded properly.

Comment: This answer is for the "single version" scenario. If you're using Remi's "multiple versions" scenario, you can use the "php56-" prefix, i.e. `yum install php56-mod_php`. The resulting library is located at `/opt/remi/php56/root/usr/lib64/httpd/modules/libphp5.so`.

Answer (score 1):

You want to type updatedb and then type locate libphp5.so.

Comment: yes i tried what you have suggested but could not locate libphp5.so

Comment: What about find / -name "*libphp5.so"?

Comment: You don't give enough information. It can be many errors when compiling php. Do you ran configure? Are you sure it compiles correctly? When I compile php I found libphp5.so in subfolder libs.

Comment: So did you look in subfolder libs?

Comment: I cant' find that file either.

Answer (score 0):

you should see the output of what is installing during the 'make install' phase. Look for your file there.
Usually the target directory is /usr/local/lib (or /usr/local/lib64), so you can try 'find' utility to look for your file in there.

Answer (score 0):

```
find / -name libphp*
```

Should locate it for you. It will be in your apache modules directory, probably: /usr/lib/httpd/modules

Comment: /root/Desktop/php-5.2.17/sapi/apache/libphp5.module.in
/root/Desktop/php-5.2.17/sapi/apache_hooks/libphp5.module.in
 this is the output of find command. i also checked in /usr/lib where i could not find httpd directory only

Comment: i tried locate and updatedb both when i give this command it says bash command ont found

Answer (score 0):

You have to install the php-apache module. In Debian for example should be:

> sudo apt install php-module

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old question but in the process of upgrading an old MediaWiki site to something new, I needed PHP 5.6 on Fedora 35. After installing remi PHP5.6 with

`dnf install http://rpms.remirepo.net/fedora/remi-release-35.rpm`

followed by

`dnf --enablerepo=remi install php56`

I could not find libphp*.so. This will give it to you.

`dnf --enablerepo=remi install php56-mod_php`

Restart httpd after and phpinfo() will display what you want it to.

Comment: On Fedora, mod_php is no more used, php-fpm is used by default for httpd or nginx

Comment: Maybe so but what I suggested is still a way to get libphp5.so

Answer (score 0):

I did a try with php 5.6.36.

I agree, `libphp5.so` is not provided if you build like that:

```
$ ./configure
$ make
$ make install INSTALL_ROOT=/tmp/php
$ ls -R /tmp/php | grep libphp
```

However, `libphp5.so` is provided if you build like that:

```
$ ./configure --with-apxs2=/usr/bin/apxs
$ make
$ make install INSTALL_ROOT=/tmp/php
$ ls -R /tmp/php | grep libphp
libphp5.so
```

So, you just have to add the `--with-apxs2=/usr/bin/apxs` option to the configure script.

You can get the help for this option like that:

```
$ ./configure --help | grep -A 1 with-apxs2=
  --with-apxs2=FILE       Build shared Apache 2.0 Handler module. FILE is the optional
                          pathname to the Apache apxs tool apxs
```

You can find the location of `apxs` on your system like that:

```
$ which apxs
/usr/bin/apxs
```

If you want to know more about `apxs`, I recommend this: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/programs/apxs.html