# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError while attempting to run PHP on Tomcat 6

Tags: php, exception, tomcat6

I used the Stack Overflow question ["Run a PHP App Using Tomcat"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779246/run-a-php-app-using-tomcat) to try to run PHP on *Tomcat 6* under *GNU/Linux*. I get the following exceptions messages:

Exception 1:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no libphp5.so in java.library.path
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
at net.php.reflect.loadLibrary(reflect.java:34)
at net.php.reflect.<clinit>(reflect.java:29)
at net.php.servlet.init(servlet.java:157)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1139)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:791)
at    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:172)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:117)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:581)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:108)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:174)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:879)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11BaseProtocol.java:665)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:528)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.runIt(LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.java:81)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:689)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Exception 2:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: net.php.servlet.send(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;Z)V
at net.php.servlet.send(Native Method)
at net.php.servlet.service(servlet.java:190)
at net.php.servlet.service(servlet.java:214)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:269)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:172)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:117)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:581)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:108)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:174)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:879)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11BaseProtocol.java:665)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:528)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.runIt(LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.java:81)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:689)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I have an entry for `libphp5.so` in the `.properties` file. I also have the `libphp5.so` file in `java.library.path`. Everything is built on and running on a 32-bit operating system. I have also copied the `phpsrvlt.jar` and `php_java.jar` files into the `tomcat/common/lib` directory.

Comment: @Sean please don't do that. That isn't fixing the formatting. I have reverted the edit. If you actually read it, they are two different exceptions

Comment: Now, on the question: we won't want to help you unless you at least show some effort on trying to understand the exception.

Comment: Please don't do what? Make it easier to read the errors?

Comment: @Sean you removed a block of text...

Comment: @Sean sorry. My mistake. You formatted the block but the display cuts it off after a few tens of lines. But that edit should have corrected the post more as I did.

Comment: Long comment: What GNU/Linux distro (and version) did you compile for and what one are you attempting to run on? Keep in mind that different kernel versions havedifferent functions. The [kernel](http://kernel.org) is backwards compatible _the the way_ to _1.0_, but newer versions add new features. If you compile against a newer kernel version that you run on, your program won't run if it depends on functions defined in newer Unix standards that the Unix standard you run against. (The kernel is based loosely around the Unix standard)

Answer (score 1):

most likely library `libphp5.so` is missing in your linux OS. Try to find it, if you succeed check whether the directory is among dirs where system is looking for libraries (e.g. environtmet variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`) (most likely it is not). If everything is ok, then the error is really somewhere in tomcat initialization.

Anyway,the error says the system is unable to find `libphp5.so`

Comment: The first exception says that it is unable to find the library in java.library.path. However, I copied the libphp5.so file manually into /lib which is one of the paths among the paths contained  in java.library.path. It is still unable to find. 
BTW, I am getting the java.library.path on my system using java code
System.getProperty("java.library.path");
I also tried setting the LD_LIBRARY_PATH to point to the directory containing the library but no luck.

Comment: oh man, copying libraries by hand - where did you see it? :P You have to install it, or compile it and install it by "make install" command. Sorry, it seems you are trying to manage something bigger than you ... Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5484047/libphp5-so-missing